# How to use npm view package versions on a long list?

Tags: npm

I want to see the available versions of `typescript`. However when I try:

```
npm view typescript versions
```

I get a list with 400+ entries and it doesn't show me everything, it stops with `... ### more items`.

I just want to see the latest versions, is there a way to do that in the command line? Or where could I check that?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `npm view typescript version` if you want to see just the last version

Comment: `dist-tags` is often useful, too: `npm view typescript dist-tags`

Comment: thanks, this is a lot useful, it shows the latest version and the next one and maybe beta versions depending on the package.